# Installing javascript driver Mongodb-native on Windows server 2008

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb

I have nodejs running with mongodb database and i'm trying to install the javascript driver mongodb-native.. When i try "npm install -g mongodb --mongodb:native"

I tried installing the same configuration on a Windows 7 machine and it works just fine. Any idea why it is not working with Windows server 2008 ?

here is the output i get from the npm install command:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.5

> bson@0.1.5 install C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\no
de_modules\bson
> node install.js || (exit 0)

================================================================================

=                                                                              =

=  Attempting to build bson c++ extension                                      =

=   Windows: no build will be attempted as binaries are prepackaged            =

=   Unix: on failure the package will still install without the C++ extension  =

=                                                                              =

================================================================================

mongodb@1.1.11 C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb
└── bson@0.1.5

C:\Users\xxx>npm ls
C:\Users\xxx
└── (empty)
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't use bson c++ extension?

Comment: how can i do that? is there another command?

Comment: What happens if you just invoke `npm install -g mongodb`?

Comment: Can you also please check what versions of `node` and `npm` you are running on the different systems.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question on the [Node MongoDB Google Group ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/node-mongodb-native) as per this  (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/node-mongodb-native/HrFjz8mTX_g) most folk seem to be using Windows desktops for testing. Christian would be delighted I'm sure to receive feedback on W2K8 testing andon the Google Group and another tester of course.

Comment: node v.0.8.11 and npm v 1.1.62

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the driver has only been tested on Windows 7, not W2K8 so it's not a surprise that it's not working.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could upload the debug information to the [Node MongoDB Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/node-mongodb-native) for further analysis and testing. The issue can be tracked better there.